# Delete files of given types IFF there are no other file types in folder

Tags: python, file, conditional-statements, file-type, delete-file

I want to delete certain files of type [cue,jpg,png,m3u,etc.] but if and only if they are in a folder by themselves or other files of [cue,jpg,png,m3u,etc.] type. I already have a function that can get me all the files of type [cue,jpg,png,m3u,etc.] in any given folder and return it as a list, but I just need to delete all of it according to the conditions above. To give an example: *File q.jpg is in a folder by itself. After myfunc() finishes, it is deleted.*

**EDIT** Sorry for unclearness. Let me give a better example:
We have two folders, *Alpha* and *Beta* in folder *Gamma*. In *Alpha*, there are three files: *1.mp3, 2.mp3, folder.jpg*. In *Beta*, there is one file *cover.jpg*. After `myfunc()` finishes, *1.mp3, 2.mp3, folder.jpg* should be untouched while *cover.jpg* should be deleted.

Comment: That's one pretty vague title!

Comment: Can you provide any example of what you want deleted and what you don't want deleted... as far as I can tell every files are in a folder so your function should just delete all files without exceptions.

Comment: Ok, @LoïcFaure-Lacroix , I added more detail

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you have two steps:

1) Given a list of extensions, get the list of all files in a folder matching that extension.

2) If all the files in your directory have an extension matching your list, remove them

Note that this doesn't include any information about how to traverse the directory structure, or which directories to test ... the sample code has a single directory hard-coded in.

```
import os       

dir = "myDirectory" 
extList = ['ext1', 'ext2', 'ext3']
allfiles = os.listdir(dir) # all files in that directory

myfiles = [] # will be appended to to only contain files with extensiosn matching extlist
for file in allfiles:
    parts = file.split('.') # split the filename based on .
    if parts[-1] in extensionlist:
        myfiles.append(file) 

if len(myfiles) == len(allfiles):
    for file in myfiles:
        path = "%s/%s" % (dir, file)
        os.remove(path)
        os.remove(file)
```

Comment: Wait, I dont understand. I can get a listing of all the files, but how do i check for those conditions? That's the part I'm confused about.

Comment: I misunderstood your original question. Does my edited answer address the part of this that you were confused about? (Note that if you want to have it work for all directories w/in a directory, you'll have to wrap the whole thing in another for loop)